# SQL Server CTE used with "group by" leads to wrong result

Tags: sql-server

I stumbled on a problem  when I try to use CTE with `GROUP BY`.

I need to concatenate strings in a 'group by' manner, that is, from the table:

```
   id value
   --------
    1    a
    1    b
    2    c
    2    d
```

I want to get the following result:

```
id vals
1  a,b
2  c,d
```

The following query will give the desired result([[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server]))

```
create table #B 
(
     id int, 
     value varchar(8)
);

insert into #B (id, value) 
values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd');

select 
    id, 
    stuff((select distinct ','+value 
           from #B 
           where id = a.id 
           for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as vals 
from #B as a
group by id;
```

But if I replace the table #B with a trivial CTE:

```
with A as 
(
     select * from #B
)
select 
    id, 
    stuff((select distinct ',' + value 
           from A 
           where id = a.id 
           for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as vals 
from A as a 
group by id
```

SQL Server returns a wrong result without any warning:

```
id vals
----------
1  a,b,c,d
2  a,b,c,d
```

Can anyone explain how the CTE query above comes up the wrong result? It is interesting to know how the CTE above is interpreted by SQL Server. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used alias `a` which refers to your `CTE` just change it and have a fun. I mean here `id=a.id` `a` refers to itself.

```
with A as (
select * from #B
)
select id, 
    stuff((select distinct ','+value from A where id=b.id for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as vals 
from A as b 
group by id
```

Comment: Oops, forgot sql is case-insensitive.  That's what happens when working with multiple languages at the same time on a long day.